# Giving a view a name causes error CS0426

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, prism

I found a lot of discussions about the error above, but unfortunately none of them could help me to understand the problem completely.

So, let's start: I have a small application which I want to test with TestComplete. That's the main reason why I - at least think - need a name for every view, to let TestComplete add every view to the NameMapping.

For the UI I build something with PRISM. Everything is happening in that one window/shell. Every view is being loaded there (with a back and next button).

So I tried to give a view a name, to have better control over the UI testing. But when I do in XAML `Name="abc"` oder `x:Name="xyz"` the build results are showing the

> Error CS0426: The type name 'MainModuleView' does not exist in the
>   type 'MainModule.MainModule' (1, 7)

I don't exactly understand, why this is happening. Could someone point me in the right direction here, please?

Answer (score 1):

The Name directive does not specify a type so I don't think that's related to the problem.

I think your problem is having namespaces and types having the same name.  If you're trying to register a view called 'MainModuleView' in the 'MainModuleView' namespace, it can't resolve the ambiguity which is why you would have to specify 'MainModuleView.MainModuleView'.

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, I had faced a similar issue and the cause was a reference to System.Windows in my project. I removed the reference and everything worked. I event read something about but I just can't find it right now! Hope this point you in the right direction.